# Expanded/collapsed state not saved after closing file

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

In Visual Studio, you can expand and collapse code without using regions, for example in a code-behind page you can collapse methods, etc... And in an ASPX page you can collapse  tags,  tags, etc...

It's useful when you have a long page and you want to focus your development on a specific part. What's cool about it too is that you can close the file and reopen it and the state of the expanded/collapsed blocks is saved exactly as you left it.

**Except in one instance. That state is not saved for tags in ASPX pages, where it would be most useful.**

I know there are some good plugins out there for VS but I couldn't find one that addresses this issue.

Has anybody got a solution?

Before you mention custom controls, they are not always convenient or feasible when trying to keep a page short and I don't consider this a solution to this problem.

Comment: That was actually the reason why I stopped using it... its state is not saved.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like this issue will stay unresolved at this time.

I opened a bug report on Microsoft Connect, if this issue is important to you please vote it up!

https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/613221/expanded-collapsed-state-not-saved-after-closing-file