# Remember my outlining or provide me any type of auto collapsing regions in ASPX files?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

My ASPX files are getting very large sometimes. When I open any ASPX file I'd like to auto hide the markup to my regions I currently define with simple comments.

What I miss is the `#region` / `#endregion` feature of C#, because those regions will auto collapse when opening my file. But so far, there is no solution for it.

Is there at least a way to tell Visual Studio to remember my outlining, so I don't have to collapse all again when opening the file again after closing it?

Comment: Duplicate question:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3401052/expanded-collapsed-state-not-saved-after-closing-file

Comment: @TonyHinkle True, but I hope anybody has done anything to it within the last 5 years ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So not sure if this is totally what you are after but it might help. The free web essentials extension for [VS 2013 enables this ability for HTML](http://vswebessentials.com/features/html#region).

Comment: Thank you so much, I already got the extension, but did not know about it. :)

Comment: I was accepting your answer too fast I guess, because when I open the file it's not collapsed by default, how can I collapse it by default?